# Using a column from a view in another view

Tags: sql, view

ViewA grabs data from TableA. ViewB needs this same column. Assuming there are specific criteria for filtering this column done on ViewA, should ViewB replicate the criteria or simply join/pull ViewA's data?  Does the answer change depending on the complexity of ViewA's criteria?

**What problems can arise if a column is pulled from another view vs duplicating the criteria in both views?**

Comment: Can you show the view definitions ?

Comment: I would say that it actually depends of the criteria. IF they will return the same information, pull the column from ViewB. However, you will not want to use a huge view with many other combinations just for only one field that could be easily copied.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Oracle is that the only drawback from layering views like you propose is performance: I've seen problems with the optimizer choosing bad plans when trying to go through views (perhaps this is improved more recently).

On the other hand, layering views can make it easier to isolate logic and help insure consistency so there's definitely a benefit.